# Troubles with my footer section in my collectionView

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I'm trying to implement a custom footer section into my collectionView, but i think i'm missing something. I'm gonna archive my code. I hope you can help me.

Thanks!!!

Custom Footer Section

```
class FooterCell: UICollectionViewCell {

let etiqueta: UILabel = {
    let label = UILabel()
    label.backgroundColor = .green
    label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return label
}()

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)

    addSubview(etiqueta)

    etiqueta.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor).isActive = true
    etiqueta.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.rightAnchor).isActive = true
    etiqueta.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true
    etiqueta.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}
```

}

The collection view class

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    collectionView?.register(FooterCell.self, forSupplementaryViewOfKind: UICollectionElementKindSectionFooter, withReuseIdentifier: "Footer") }

override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {

    var reusableView = FooterCell()



    if kind == UICollectionElementKindSectionFooter {

        reusableView = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: kind,  withReuseIdentifier: "Footer", for: indexPath) as! FooterCell

        reusableView.etiqueta.backgroundColor = .green
    }

    return reusableView

}
```

Comment: there is one more method to specify height for footer cell implement that.

Comment: Thank you, it worked!!!
If you want, post it as an answer, so i can mark it like that!!!

Comment: okk sure just a minute.I am on phone will modify later

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this method-:

```
optional func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, 
                  layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, 
                  referenceSizeForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGSize
```